# Why does Elasticsearch ignore_malformed add malformed value to index?

Tags: elasticsearch, serilog, filebeat

I am using Serilog in C# to create a log file, which is ingested by Filebeat and sent via Logstash to Elasticsearch. The Elasticsearch indexes conform to ECS 1.5.

The log file sometimes contains erroneous values for the field "host.ip", it can contain values like "localhost:5000". This lead to rejected log posts, since a string like that cannot be converted into an ip number. This is all expected, and the issue of correcting the log file is not in the scope of this question.

I decided to add the "ignore_malformed: true" setting, on the index level. After that, the log posts are no longer rejected - I can find them in Elasticsearch. So, the setting is proven to have had effect. BUT the field "host.ip" now actually contains the malformed value "localhost:5000". I can't see how that is even possible, it is not what I expected or wanted.

[image]

From the documetation of "ignore_malformed", it would appear as if values that do not match the field type are supposed to be discarded - not written into the field. I also find no added "_ignored" field.

It's as if setting ignore_malformed to true actually allows the malformed data into the index, instead of dropping it. I'm expecting/wanting the field to be empty, if the value is malformed. Is this a bug, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever you send in the source document will always be there, ES will never modify it. However, the fact that you're now specifying `ignore_malformed` means that ES will not try to index malformed data, but the value will still be visible in your source document.

Comment: So... Maybe it's just an issue of me not having got the terms right.
I thought "indexing" was more or less equal to "saving the data", and hence when the docs say "The malformed field is not indexed", that would mean that the data wouldn't be saved in Elastic at all. I have got a million follow up questions but I'll try to stay calm and just try out a few things based on what you just wrote. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: The source document is stored "as is" in the `_source` field. However, if the value is malformed (i.e. `localhost:5000`), then it will not be stored/indexed and the field `host.ip` field will be empty for that document.

Comment: But... that's not what I'm seeing. I'm adding an image to the original question to clarify, would you agree that this seems strange?

Comment: What you're seeing is the value taken from the source document (using [source filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-source-filtering)). Again, the `server.ip` field present **in your JSON document** will not be touched by ES. The value of that field, however, will not be indexed by ES in the inverted index.

Comment: As a test, you can try to run a terms aggregation on `server.ip` and you can be certain that you won't see a bucket with a key like `localhost:5000`, which means that the value is not indexed

Comment: So the results shown in the "Discover" view in Kibana is coming from "_source"... I thought it was the indexed data, but this makes much more sense. Considering stuff like word stemming... wow. It's fairly obvious when you say it, but my mental image of how it works has been flawed. I truly appreciate your help here, an eye opener for me!

Comment: PS. I eventually found some documents with "_ignored" field on them, so there's no doubt it's all working as it should.

Comment: Yes, in Discover you really see the source document. Whatever is indexed is used at search time and not really displayed anywhere.